# last 20 data in ascending order in php

Tags: php, html, sql, database

How to get last 20 data of database in php query that will appear in ascending order exactly shown in database? I am asking because if i write *`desc limit 20`* then it will show last data first and last 20th data at last. Now if i write *`asc limit 20`* then it will give first 20 data from table.
I am using query
*`select * from table_name order by id desc limit 20`*
 for last 20 data.

Comment: use asc instead of desc

Comment: @scaisEdge That will return the _first_ 20 rows. OP wants last 20 rows ascending.

Comment: i have edited my question i want last 20 data but in asc order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need  the 20 asc from the all desc you could use

```
select * from (
     select * from table_name order by id desc 
 ) t order by id asc limit 20
```

Comment: i think your result same as: select * from table_name order by id asc limit 20 :)

Comment: @sukalogika   no this from  the reslt in descent orderd  invert the  top 20

Comment: @scaisEdge, is there any advantage (performance) for this query comparing to sukalogika's answer? just to know..

Comment: @AbdulRasheed   good question ... .  the limit clause in an ordered  select  is applied  on the result ... so there are not appreciable results  ....because all the select and order by is performed  befoe the limit filter

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT * FROM `table_name` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 20
)
AS temp
ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

Select last 20, and then sort them with asc